# Como adicionar dependência do SQL Server no Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Estou tentando adicionar a dependência do `SQL Server` em meu `POM` porém dá `Missing Artifact`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esse artefato não está carregado nos repositórios Maven on-line.

A solução é baixar a biblioteca do [site da Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) e adicioná-la manualmente ao seu repositório maven local, com o comando:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Fonte: [Missing artifact com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19537786/1964435)

---

Caso você use o Maven através do plugin do Eclipse, não será possível usar a linha de comando, e deve-se usar a própria interface do Eclipse para instalar a biblioteca no seu repositório local. Conforme a dica do @BrunoCésar nos comentários, faça o seguinte:

Clique com o botão direito no nome do projeto, vá em "Run As > Run Configurations..."

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Na janela que se abrir, clique com o botão direito em "Maven Build" depois selecione "New".

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Preencha o campo "Goals" com o comando:

```
install:install-file -Dfile=D:\sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

No campo "-Dfile=" informe o caminho completo do arquivo `.jar`.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Ao rodar o comando, se tudo correr bem você verá a mensagem "BUILD SUCCESS":

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

E o pom.xml aceitará normalmente a dependência `sqljdbc4`, e não mostrará mais o erro:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Esse comando é no prompt mesmo ou em outro lugar? Tenho que estar dentro do diretório que está o .jar do sql server?

Comment: Pode ser no prompt mesmo, vc tem que ter configurado o variable paths corretamente. Tem que ser na mesma pasta em que está o .jar, mas essa pasta pode ser qualquer uma.

Comment: Acho que eu não tenho o Maven configurado nas variáveis de ambiente. Vou dar uma pesquisada para configura-lo

Comment: Aqui ensina a configurar: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei onde fica minha pasta do Maven, pois baixei ele pelo Eclipse kk

Comment: Boa dúvida. Vou procurar aqui também.

Comment: @Techies você pode executar pelo maven *embedded* do eclipse também, caso não queira instalá-lo. Basta ir em `Run Configurations > Maven Build`, botão direito sobre, `New` e em `Goals` inclua isto, como o @Math disse: `install:install-file -Dfile=D:\sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar`. Coloque um caminho completo por garantia =)

Comment: Aqui não aparece Goals

Comment: Instalei o Maven novamente e usei o comando e deu certo, obrigado

Comment: @Techies acabei de fazer um teste com o Maven do Eclipse e consegui fazer de acordo com a informação do Bruno César tb. Realmente quando se instala o plugin do maven não existe um mvn.exe em algum lugar, tem que fazer pela interface do Eclipse. Mas como vc já resolveu seu problema, então blz :)

Comment: Beleza, eu consegui aqui também das duas maneiras. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Math, creio que essa resposta esteja datada: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 ; acabei de testar na minha máquina e funcionou

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado verdade, agora pode ser feito de maneira mais fácil, vou editar a resposta para que fique genérica para casos similares a esse

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não me esqueci não, só faltou eu parar para criar um exemplo melhor, tem que dar uma modificada boa na resposta então tenho que parar para fazer só isso, vou ver se faço amanhã

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra forma para importar tal dependência em seu projeto do Eclipse, pode ser observada pelos passos abaixo.

1. Baixar a [biblioteca](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) do site oficial da microsoft. Ao extrair o conteúdo do arquivo em questão, é possível encontrar diferentes bibliotecas para cada versão do Java, por exemplo: sqljdbc41.jar (JRE7) ou sqljdbc42.jar (JRE8).
2. Clicar com o botão direito do mouse no projeto, selecionar "Import" e clicar na opção "Import".
3. Expandir o diretório Maven, selecionar a opção "Install or deploy an artifact to a Maven repository" e clicar em "Next".
4. Preencher os campos conforme exemplo:

`Artifact file:` caminho para o diretório da biblioteca baixada anteriormente. Ex.: D:\lib\sqljdbc42.jar ou /Volumes/FILES/lib/sqljdbc42.jar.
`Group id:` com.microsoft.sqlserver
`Artifact id:` sqljdbc4
`Version:` 4.2
`Packaging:` jar

1. Agora basta incluir uma nova dependência entre as TAG's  do arquivo pom.xml do Maven em seu projeto.

```xml
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
<version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

6. Para finalizar, atualize seu projeto e a dependência será carregada com sucesso!

Comment: Se a ideia é usar o Maven, baixar a lib só mascara o problema. Além do mais, outro usuário do projeto precisaria fazer esses mesmos procedimentos manuais.

Comment: Infelizmente a Microsoft não forneceu tal biblioteca em um repositório oficial do Maven e a única opção que temos é incluir a mesma manualmente. O post que eu fiz é para solucionar o problema do usuário, porém não pode ser considerado como um uso errado. Caso você tenha uma solução se não a que eu informei, favor compartilhar conosco.